# Ethernet UNCLAIMED

Tags: ethernet

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS recently upgraded

Wired ethernet suddenly becomes "UNCLAIMED". Where I can seek this issue?

Below there are posted some commands I used for investigation and my expectation is to get a little more help from the Linux experts.

I am not sure first what driver is compiled (presumably r8169 as reported by lsmod below) and then what driver should kernel used for Realtek 810xE?

I did not remember uninstalling any ethernet driver/module so why I do have to look for a driver since I never had ethernet issues on this box over the last 4-5 years?

Thanks a million.

UPDATE: the ethernet issue was somehow solved. I had to deploy r8101 instead of r8169. I have no idea why and how r8169 was installed and don't know if r8101 is the right choice but works fine

ifconfig does not list ethernet

```
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2318  bytes 225667 (225.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2318  bytes 225667 (225.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.106  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.0.255
        inet6 fe80::ee36:68b6:3b81:3351  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 90:48:9a:e5:08:12  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 79882  bytes 93278170 (93.2 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 67136  bytes 9769521 (9.7 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

lshw -C net

```
 *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: 90:48:9a:e5:08:12
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=5.4.0-25-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.106 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:96 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90700000-90703fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0c)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SATA AHCI Controller (rev 0c)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx, Celeron N2000 Series USB xHCI (rev 0c)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0c)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0c)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 0c)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 0c)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 0c)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 0c)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0c)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Atom Processor E3800 Series SMBus Controller (rev 0c)
02:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

ethtool enp4s0

```
Settings for enp4s0:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: No such device
Cannot get message level: No such device
Cannot get link status: No such device
```

lsmod

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bnep                   24576  2
ccm                    20480  3
vboxnetadp             28672  0
vboxnetflt             28672  0
vboxdrv               487424  2 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     61440  1
snd_hda_codec_realtek   118784  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ledtrig_audio          16384  2 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_realtek
uvcvideo               98304  0
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      24576  1 intel_rapl_msr
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
intel_soc_dts_thermal    20480  0
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
intel_soc_dts_iosf     20480  1 intel_soc_dts_thermal
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
snd_hda_intel          53248  3
snd_intel_dspcfg       24576  1 snd_hda_intel
coretemp               20480  0
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek
videodev              225280  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
kvm_intel             286720  0
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
mei_hdcp               24576  0
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
i915                 1986560  13
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
kvm                   663552  1 kvm_intel
hci_uart              126976  0
rtl8188ee             102400  0
snd                    90112  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
rtsx_pci_ms            24576  0
rtl_pci                28672  1 rtl8188ee
drm_kms_helper        184320  1 i915
rtlwifi                90112  2 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee
punit_atom_debug       16384  0
mac80211              843776  3 rtl_pci,rtl8188ee,rtlwifi
soundcore              16384  1 snd
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
cfg80211              704512  2 rtlwifi,mac80211
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
cryptd                 24576  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
btqca                  20480  1 hci_uart
btrtl                  24576  1 hci_uart
intel_cstate           20480  0
btbcm                  16384  1 hci_uart
btintel                24576  1 hci_uart
mei_txe                28672  1
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
mei                   106496  3 mei_hdcp,mei_txe
bluetooth             581632  12 btrtl,btqca,btintel,hci_uart,btbcm,bnep
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
joydev                 24576  0
ecc                    28672  1 ecdh_generic
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              20480  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
rfkill_gpio            16384  0
binfmt_misc            24576  1
sch_fq_codel           20480  5
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
drm                   491520  10 drm_kms_helper,i915
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
hid_logitech_hidpp     40960  0
hid_logitech_dj        24576  0
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 57344  1 hid_logitech_dj
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         28672  0
r8169                  90112  0
psmouse               155648  0
rtsx_pci               69632  2 rtsx_pci_sdmmc,rtsx_pci_ms
ahci                   40960  3
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
realtek                24576  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
i2c_i801               32768  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof
video                  49152  1 i915
dw_dmac                16384  0
i2c_hid                28672  0
dw_dmac_core           28672  1 dw_dmac
hid                   131072  5 i2c_hid,usbhid,hid_generic,hid_logitech_dj,hid_logitech_hidpp
```

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1195475/968501

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version? If it is 20.04, delete this question and report a bug.

Comment: How happend the 5.4 kernel appear there then?

Answer (score 3):

**TLDR: Update your linux kernel**

I was facing the same after after upgrading Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. For me not only Ethernet but WiFi was also `Unclaimed` state(output of `sudo lshw -C network`). Not only this, my trackpad was also broken.

The linux kernel was `5.8.0-X-generic`.

After booting into Ubuntu recovery mode with some other version of kernel(I chose the lowest one), I could see the networking devices, but this time in `DISABLED` state.

Wierdly, after running, `nmcli dev show`, the `DISABLED` state was gone. And I could access the internet.

I updated the linux kernel to the latest one. I followed [Method #2 of this tutorial](https://linuxhint.com/update_ubuntu_kernel_20_04/).

Once kernel is updated, you can reboot in normal mode. Hopefully, it would work.

---

PS

You can take help of https://linux-hardware.org/ to check whether your Ethernet and Wireless adapter is supported by a specific OS version and kernel version.